# BufRead,BufNew keymaps modify current buffer instead of opened buffer in Neovim and Vim

Tags: vim, neovim, keymapping

I can't scratch my head around why my keymaps in C++ file buffer are getting overwritten by rules for `in` file. I though `BufRead` executes after opening new file, right?

I have the following `vimrc` configuration:

```
autocmd FileType cpp
    \  nnoremap <buffer> <f5> :up<cr>:!g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wno-sign-conversion -O2 -o a.out % && ./a.out < in<cr>
    \| nnoremap <buffer> <f6> :split in<cr>

autocmd BufRead,BufNew in
    \  nnoremap <buffer> <f5> :up<cr>:!./a.out < in<cr>
    \| nnoremap <buffer> <f6> :wq<cr>
    \| echom "in file loaded " . winbufnr(0)
```

Output in vim after F6 (`:mess`):

```
in file loaded 1
in file loaded 2
```

Output in Nvim after F6:

```
in file loaded 1
```

There is no output before pressing F6.

When I open file `in` from `test.cpp` (either through F6 or direct `:sp`), C++ keymaps are no longer there, from `test.cpp`:

```
:nnoremap <buffer>

n  <F6>        *@:wq<CR>                                               
n  <F5>        *@:up<CR>:!./a.out < in<CR>
```

My other `F5` keymaps for other files are working just fine. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Replaced `BufNew` with `BufNewFile` event and it works as expected